# Donut charts for Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Hi I am trying to implement a doughnut chart for wp8.1 app . I don't have any idea where to look at as having real problem in finding any specific nugget package or toolkit that can be used. If anyone can guide or share the code for creating a doughnut chart it would be really great.

I am even trying to create multiple ellipses so that they can be placed upon each other such that it makes a doughnut shape. But no success. here is the code:

Comment: Ok not exactly what you are after, but maybe this usercontrol can help you reach this kind of chart control https://gist.github.com/JanJoris/d9d78f748047c157188f it's a circular progressring ( what can be used with or without animation ) with several bindable properties to set values

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the winrt toolkit there are quite a few different charts I did not see a chart control matching your requirements.

http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

If that does not meet your requirements I would then modify the xaml brewer's gauge control

http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/06/24/A-Modern-UI-radial-gauge-control-for-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx

This control is part of the xaml toolkit as well

Comment: Glad to hear you found exactly what you were looking for